# How to Request an Update to A Perfectly Good Question

Tags: discussion

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510851/running-clojure-web-applications-in-production) on Clojure Noir and Apache Integration asks the same question I want to ask, but it's from 2011, and I would like to know what, if anything, has changed. What is the best protocol to use, re-ask the question (I would ask it somewhat differently from the OP) and site the original question, or edit the original question?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a bounty to the old existing question and explain your intention in the bounty note.